# Яка етимологія синонімів "чарувати" та "чаклувати"?

Tags: етимологія, синоніми

[Словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/chakluvaty) каже, що:

Чарувати - Діяти, впливати на когось, щось чарами; чаклувати."

Чаклувати - Займатися чаклунством.

Чаклунство, відповідно ж - це за старовинними марновірними уявленнями — магічні дії, рухи й замовляння, за допомогою яких нібито можна вплинути на людей і природу.

Майже такі ж значення подані і в [Українському тлумачному словнику](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/195438/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), і на [Офіційному сайті Української мови](http://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/ch/charuvati/46-1-0-5434).

Отже, виходить, що це синоніми, але яка ж етимологія цих слів?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Продовжимо](/q/3340/585)

ЕСУМ 6, 227

> **чакло** (*колосове*) (бот.) «актея колосиста (чернесь), Actaea spicata L.» Нед, Mak; — не зовсім ясне; можливо, повʼязане з *чаклува́ти*, оскільки рослина викликає тяжке отруєння. — Нейштадт 252—253
>
> **чаклувати** чарувати», [*чакли́*] «чари», [*чаклівни́ця*] «чарівниця» Нед, [*чаклі́й*] «чаклун», *чаклування*, *чаклун*, *чаклунка*, *чаклунство*; — специфічно українське утворення не зовсім ясного походження; реконструювалася (Потебня РФВ 1 266) первісна форма **шакловати*, яка також не має достовірної етимології; можливо, основа цього слова тюркського походження, пор. тур. çakmak «забивати; викрешувати (вогонь); блискати; здогадуватися, кумекати».

280

> **чар** «привабливість, чарівливість; чаклунство, чаклунське зілля», [*чара́*] «чари» Нед, *ча́ри* (мн.), [*ча́рінь*] «пішментні плями на обличчі вагітної жінки» Корз, [*чарі́вка*] «чарівниця», *чарівни́к*, *чарівни́цтво*, *чарівни́ця*, [*чарови́на*] «чаклунське зілля», [*чаровни́к*] «чарівник» Бі, [*чарівки́й*] «чарівний», *чарівли́вий*, *чарівни́й*, *чарівни́цький*, *чарівни́чий*, *чарува́ти*, [*пречарови́тий*] «чарівливий», ст. *чароване*;
>
> російська, білоруська *ча́ры* (мн.), др. *чаръ*, польська czar, чеська, слн. čár, слц. čar, болгарська, македонська *чар*, схв. *ча̂р*, стсл. **чаръ**;
>
> псл. čarъ/čara;
>
> споріднене з лит. keraĩ (мн.) «чари, чаклунство», kerė́ti «чарувати, чаклувати», ав. ċāra- «засіб», перс. čār «тс.», čāra «засіб, допомога, хитрощі», дінд. kṛṇṓti «робить», karṓti «тс.», kṛtyā́ «дія, вчинок», ав. kərənaoiti «робить», кімр. peri «робити»; іє. *k"er- «тс.»; менш перекониві повʼязання псл. čarъ з грецькою κείρω «стрижу; рубаю; знищую» (Brückner PF 7, 177) або з грецькою κήρηξ «оповісник, провісник», лат. carmen «пісня, наспів», дінд. kīrtíṣ «слава, звістка» (Ильинский РФВ 61. 236—237) — Фасмер 4 317; …